# Copy files based on weekday

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to run a VBS script that copies differ files to the same destination folder 
based on Weekdays. 
So if today is Saturday (System time), file 1.text will be sent to destination but if that's Sunday, file 2.text will be sent to destination. Wrote the following with no success...

```
dim FSO
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If Weekday(1,True))
FSO.CopyFile "C:\Users\sdu\Desktop\Source\1.txt", "C:\Users\sdu\Desktop\Destination\"  

if Weekday(2,True))
FSO.CopyFile "C:\Users\sdu\Desktop\Source\2.txt", "C:\Users\sdu\Desktop\Destination\"  

if Weekday(3,True))
FSO.CopyFile "C:\Users\sdu\Desktop\Source\3.txt", "C:\Users\sdu\Desktop\Destination\"  

Else
FSO.CopyFile "C:\Users\sdu\Desktop\Source\4.txt", "C:\Users\sdu\Desktop\Destination\"
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear to me what you want to copy. Do you have separate files for each day (i.e. `1.txt` through `7.txt`)? Or do you have separate files for the first 3 days (`1.txt`, `2.txt`, `3.txt`) and another one (`4.txt`) for the rest of the week?

In case of the latter I'd use a `Select Case` statement:

```
src = "C:\Users\sdu\Desktop\Source"
dst = "C:\Users\sdu\Desktop\Destination"

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

n = Weekday(Date, vbSaturday)
Select Case n
  Case 1, 2, 3 : FSO.CopyFile FSO.BuildPath(src, n & ".txt"), dst & "\"
  Case Else    : FSO.CopyFile FSO.BuildPath(src, "4.txt"), dst & "\"
End Select
```

or an `If` statement:

```
src = "C:\Users\sdu\Desktop\Source"
dst = "C:\Users\sdu\Desktop\Destination"

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

n = Weekday(Date, vbSaturday)
If n < 4 Then
  FSO.CopyFile FSO.BuildPath(src, n & ".txt"), dst & "\"
Else
  FSO.CopyFile FSO.BuildPath(src, "4.txt"), dst & "\"
End If
```

Otherwise you could simply do this:

```
src = "C:\Users\sdu\Desktop\Source"
dst = "C:\Users\sdu\Desktop\Destination"

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

FSO.CopyFile FSO.BuildPath(src, Weekday(Date, vbSaturday) & ".txt"), dst & "\"
```

Comment: +1 for the nice idea to use vbSaturday to align the weekday- and the file-numbers.

Comment: Thanks for that Ansgar. I have changed the 2nd script and it works as I expected. I only need to files to be copied during weekdays not during the weekend. 

src = "C:\Users\sdu\Desktop\Source"
dst = "C:\Users\sdu\Desktop\Destination"

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
n = Weekday(Date)
If n < 6 Then
  FSO.CopyFile FSO.BuildPath(src, n & ".txt"), dst & "\"
End If

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary to map weekday(number)s to file names:

```
Option Explicit

Dim dicWD2File : Set dicWD2File = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
dicWD2File(1) = "2.txt"
dicWD2File(2) = "3.txt"
dicWD2File(3) = "4.txt"
dicWD2File(4) = "4.txt"
dicWD2File(5) = "4.txt"
dicWD2File(6) = "4.txt"
dicWD2File(7) = "1.txt"

Dim dtToday : dtToday = Date()
Dim nWD : nWD = Weekday(dtToday, vbSunday) ' nail down: Sunday => 1
WScript.Echo dtToday, nWD, WeekdayName(nWD)
If dicWD2File.Exists(nWD) Then
   WScript.Echo "=> copy:", Replace("C:\Users\sdu\Desktop\Source\@", "@", dicWD2File(nWD))
Else
   WScript.Echo "no such weekday:", nWD
End If
```

output:

```
cscript 26500866.vbs
22.10.2014 4 Wednesday
=> copy: C:\Users\sdu\Desktop\Source\4.txt
```

(That way you have to learn the correct syntax of IF statements just once!)